# Actor-director partnership

Tags: casting, film-industry, american-cinema

Which is the longest actor-director partnership? I'm talking about movies where a given director works with the same actor/actress in a leading role.

Johnny Depp & Tim Burton is one of the first ones that came to my mind. Another one could be Leonardo DiCaprio & Martin Scorsese.

Comment: I have no idea whether this happened, but if these two persons (actor/director) were the same, would that count?

Comment: @Jenayah That wouldn't count. Yeah Ben Stiller, I'm talking to you

Comment: Also this is tagged [american-cinema], but would you be interested in, say, Indian movies as well? (once again I have no idea if the answer lies there, but in case it does, let's clarify the question :) )

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_film_director_and_actor_collaborations

Answer (score 3):

### Arguably, [John Ford & John Wayne](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls070058686/). - 24 to 35 years (1928/39 - 1963)

Ford directed Wayne in *Stagecoach* (1939) and continued to feature him until at least 1963 with *Donovan's Reef*.

In fact, Ford had directed Wayne in several movies prior to 1939 (as far back as 1928) but *Stagecoach* was Wayne's breakout role.